# Get index of selected option with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, select, indexing

I'm a little bit confused about how to get an index of a selected option from a HTML `<select>` item.

On [this](http://www.theextremewebdesigns.com/blog/jquery-get-selected-index-jquery-get-selected-option-index-2-ways/) page there are two methods described. However, both are always returning `-1`. Here is my jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#dropDownMenuKategorie").change(function(){
        alert($("#dropDownMenuKategorie option:selected").index());
        alert($("select[name='dropDownMenuKategorie'] option:selected").index());
    });
});
```

and in html

```
(...)
<select id="dropDownMenuKategorie">
    <option value="gastronomie">Gastronomie</option>
    <option value="finanzen">Finanzen</option>
    <option value="lebensmittel">Lebensmittel</option>
    <option value="gewerbe">Gewerbe</option>
    <option value="shopping">Shopping</option>
    <option value="bildung">Bildung</option>
</select>
(...)
```

Why this behavior?  Is there any chance that the `select` is not "ready" at the moment of assigning its `change()` method? Additionally, changing `.index()` to `.val()` is returning the right value, so that's what confuses me even more.

Comment: Such an old question but the real problem is the `[name=]` used when select has `id` on it. The `[0].selectedIndex` and `option:selected` -answers below are both ok.

Answer (score 394, accepted):

The first methods seem to work in the browsers that I tested, but the option tags doesn't really correspond to actual elements in all browsers, so the result may vary.

Just use the `selectedIndex` property of the DOM element:

```
alert($("#dropDownMenuKategorie")[0].selectedIndex);
```

#### Update:

Since version 1.6 jQuery has the `prop` method that can be used to read properties:

```
alert($("#dropDownMenuKategorie").prop('selectedIndex'));
```

Comment: @Joan.bdm jquery does not have `selectedIndex` property. Adding `[0]` converts the jquery object to a javascript object which has the `selectedIndex` property. This example won't work without `[0]`

Comment: @JasonL.: `selectedIndex` is a property, and there is no corresponding attribute. The `attr` method might work to read the property in versions earlier than 1.6, but not from that version.

Comment: @Guffa Any idea as to why the `selectedIndex` doesn't start from 0 with the first option?

Comment: @adamj: Then you are doing something wrong. The `selectedIndex` property is zero based. I checked the documentation and even tried it myself to be truly 100% sure about this.

Comment: @Guffa Thank you very much on your reply Guffa! Your message actually made something click. I use Select2 and I forgot to account for the placeholder when marrying it up to an array. Silly small mistake. Thanks again :)

Comment: thank you for providing the `prop` method -- it got me past a snag where other "solutions" elsewhere did not work

Comment: The answer by user167517 is the way to go since you are using jquery

Answer (score 102):

Good way to solve this in Jquery manner

```
$("#dropDownMenuKategorie option:selected").index()
```

Comment: I like that this answer doesn't require the `[0]` of OP's preferred answer and as a python dev, I can really appreciate the readability of this answer.

Comment: The OP already tried that. The code is identical to the first method in the question.

Comment: I was looking for this and found it:
document.querySelector('.jsPaymentStatusOptions option[selected]').index

Answer (score 21):

You can use the [`.prop(propertyName)`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) function to get a property from the first element in the jQuery object.

```
var savedIndex = $(selectElement).prop('selectedIndex');
```

This keeps your code within the jQuery realm and also avoids the other option of using a selector to find the selected option. You can then restore it using the overload:

```
$(selectElement).prop('selectedIndex', savedIndex);
```

Answer (score 19):

I have a slightly different solution based on the answer by user167517. In my function I'm using a variable for the id of the select box I'm targeting.

```
var vOptionSelect = "#productcodeSelect1";
```

The index is returned with:

```
$(vOptionSelect).find(":selected").index();
```

Answer (score 7):

try this

```
 alert(document.getElementById("dropDownMenuKategorie").selectedIndex);
```

Comment: What's with all the alerts?

Comment: @Beanwah - It's the best way to test anything! ;)

Comment: @JoePC no its not. console.log() will do better

Comment: @reiner.luke - ;) = facetiousness

Answer (score 7):

[selectedIndex](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_select_selectedindex.asp) is a JavaScript Select Property. For jQuery you can use this code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $("#dropDownMenuKategorie").change(function() {
    // I personally prefer using console.log(), but if you want you can still go with the alert().
    console.log($(this).children('option:selected').index());
  });
});
```

Answer (score 4):

You can get the index of the select box by using : .prop() method of JQuery

Check This :

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

});

function check(){
    alert($("#NumberSelector").prop('selectedIndex'));
    alert(document.getElementById("NumberSelector").value);
}
</script>
</head>

<body bgcolor="yellow">
<div>
<select id="NumberSelector" onchange="check()">
    <option value="Its Zero">Zero</option>
    <option value="Its One">One</option>
    <option value="Its Two">Two</option>
    <option value="Its Three">Three</option>
    <option value="Its Four">Four</option>
    <option value="Its Five">Five</option>
    <option value="Its Six">Six</option>
    <option value="Its Seven">Seven</option>
</select>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually just reiterating what has already been stated a little differently:

```
$("#dropDownMenuKategorie").change(function() {
     var Selection = $("#dropDownMenuKategorie option:selected");
     alert(Selection.index());
     alert(Selection.val());
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Assume You have jquery loaded. So

HTML :

```
<select id="dropDownMenuKategorie">
    <option value="gastronomie">Gastronomie</option>
    <option value="finanzen">Finanzen</option>
    <option value="lebensmittel">Lebensmittel</option>
    <option value="gewerbe">Gewerbe</option>
   <option value="shopping">Shopping</option>
   <option value="bildung">Bildung</option>
</select>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#dropDownMenuKategorie").change(function(){
       var selIndex = $(this).prop('selectedIndex');
       var selVal = $("#dropDownMenuKategorie option:selected").val();
       var selText = $("#dropDownMenuKategorie option:selected").text();
       console.log(selIndex + selVal + selText );
    });
});
```