# Get index or value of clicked option from multiple select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have multiple select in which I want to clicked option on which I cliked.

E.g. If I click on first option then display first option `index` or `value`.

**HTML Code**

```
<select class="founder_designation" rel="Designation" placeholder="Designation" multiple="multiple" name="designation">
<option value="">-- Select Designation --</option>
<option value="chairman_managing_director">Chairman &amp; Managing Director</option>
<option selected="selected" value="director" >Director</option>
<option value="whole_time_director">Whole Time Director</option>
<option value="other">Other</option>
</select>
```

**jQuery Code**

```
$(".founder_designation").on("change",function(){
  alert($(this).val());   //It display all selected options with comma separated
})
```

**[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m3coohLr/1/)**

Comment: possible duplicate of [get index of selected option with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13556941/get-index-of-selected-option-with-jquery)

Comment: @DanielA.White I have multiple dropdown with same className

Comment: just change your selector.

Comment: @DanielA.White You might be wrong understand my question I want last clicked option not selected option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this will do the trick,

```
$('.founder_designation').on('click','option',function(){
 alert($(this).val());
});
```

if you want all the value then try some thing like this,

```
$('.founder_designation').on('click','option',function(){

    alert("clicked value:"+$(this).val());

    $a=$('.founder_designation option:selected');
    $str='';
    for($i=0;$i<$a.length;$i++){
        $str+=$('.founder_designation option:selected:eq('+$i+')').val()+",";
    }

    alert("all selected :"+$str);
});
```

Check the demo 
[JS FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/c1q8th8v/)

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
$('.founder_designation option:selected').val();
```

If you have several selects with the classname `founder_designation` you could do this:

```
$('.founder_designation option').click(function(e) {
   var value = $(this).val();
   alert(value);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".founder_designation").on("change",function(e){
  alert(e.target.value);
  // OR
  alert($(e.target).val());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let previouslySelected = []; // declare as a global array

$("#your-select-picker-id").change(function () {

    let currentlySelected   = $(this).val(); // ids [1, 2, 3]
    let isAdding            = currentlySelected.length > previouslySelected.length;

    if ( isAdding )
    {
        lastSelectedId = currentlySelected.find( ( element ) => ! previouslySelected.includes(element) )
    }
    else
    {
        lastSelectedId = previouslySelected.find( ( element ) => ! currentlySelected.includes(element) )
    }
    previouslySelected = currentlySelected;
});
```