# How to get selected dropdown inside the table

Tags: jquery, html-table

I'm trying to get each row in array. I get the value of all textbox but the problem is the dropdown list. It doesn't get the current selected index. Here is my code so far:

```
var table_data = [];    
        $('#table_assign tr').each(function () {    
            var row_data = [];    
            $('td', this).each(function () {    
                row_data.push($(this).text());    
            });    
            table_data.push(row_data);    
        });    
        alert(table_data);
    }
```

I want to get the current selected index in each row. How to do that? any ideas?

---

Update:

This is how I add the  data into the table

```
 $.get('LoadserviceSplit', {"sectcode": 001},
    function (jsonResponse) {
        if (jsonResponse != null) {
            var table2 = $("#table_assign");
            $.each(jsonResponse, function (key, value) {
                                             var rowNew = $("<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>");
                rowNew.children().eq(0).text(value['serviceId']);
                rowNew.children().eq(1).text(value['title']);
                  rowNew.children().eq(2).html('<input type="text" class="selectko"/>');                        
                rowNew.children().eq(3).html('<select class="selectko" id="employee' + ctr+ '">'); // this is the dropdown list
                rowNew.children().eq(4).html('<select class="form-control input-sm">\n\
                                            <option value="Low">Normal</option>\n\
                                            <option value="Normal">Low</option>\n\
                                            <option value="High">High</option></select>');
                rowNew.children().eq(5).html('<input type="text" class="form-control input-sm"/>');

            });

          ctr++;

        }

    });
```

the id of the option box is employee with auto increment. sample "employee1",then next dropdown list id will be "employee2".

Comment: What is the id or class of dropdown ?

Comment: i update my question sir please check update

Comment: possible duplicate of [get index of selected option with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13556941/get-index-of-selected-option-with-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

To get the selected index try using the selected selector: http://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/

For example (this will also get your index):

`$("select[name='mydropdown'] option:selected").index()`

To just grab the element:
`$("select[name='mydropdown'] option:selected")`

However, if possible you should use the ID selector (faster):
`$("#mydropdown option:selected")`